# JS clearTimeout fails to work even with var set outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, settimeout

I am trying to get a preview to display on hover, but if I move my mouse off, I want the preview not to display. Currently, if I quickly move my mouse across the ".searchRecord" element it will display after 300ms anyway, and be "stuck" as the mouse off function was called before the setTimeout function could finish. if I let me cursor stay on the element until the preview displays everything works just fine.

I set the variable outside the function as I read elsewhere, however, it doesn't reset. I'm a bit stumped.

```
var timer;
$('.searchRecord').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.previewLoad').show();
    var current = '#'+$(this).children('div').attr('id');

    //slight delay before hover so they can select what they want
    var timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
        $(current).fadeIn('fast');
        $(current).siblings('.previewLoad').hide();
    }, 300);
}, function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    var current = '#'+$(this).children('div').attr('id');
    previewTimeouter(current);
});
```

Comment: That will not solve your problem but think about using one of the million tooltip plugins for jQuery, there you can set your delay settings as well and you don't have to care about the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have duplicated timer declaration. remove the `var` in `var timer` in the hover callback.

```
var timer;
$('.searchRecord').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.previewLoad').show();
    var current = '#'+$(this).children('div').attr('id');

    //slight delay before hover so they can select what they want
    timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
        $(current).fadeIn('fast');
        $(current).siblings('.previewLoad').hide();
    }, 300);
}, function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    var current = '#'+$(this).children('div').attr('id');
    previewTimeouter(current);
});
```

Comment: That was it. My first question on Stack Overflow was total fail. Thanks a ton for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `var timer` again inside of the hover callback, which scopes it to that function and shadows the parent `timer` variable.

Remove that internal `var` and all shall be well.